# Breakpoints work differently than in examples

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I'm coding in C++ with Visual Studio. As I'm following along in a YouTube tutorial by The Cherno, he suggests placing breakpoints in certain places. He places them there and they work. When I place them in the same places in my copy of his code, the debugger doesn't run them (the red circle which marks breakpoints turns black upon debugging). The particular place I'm trying to break at is the initialization of a variable as an integer.

I notice that every place I try to put a breakpoint besides the first bracket of my main() turns black and doesn't run.

This is what The Cherno's code looks like with one working breakpoint.
[image: This is what The Cherno's code looks like with one working breakpoint.]

This is what my code looks like. If I move the first breakpoint down to where his is, it doesn't run. Also note no other breakpoint runs.
[image: This is what my code looks like. If I move the first breakpoint down to where his is, it doesn't run. Also note no other breakpoint runs.]

I have made sure I'm running in debug mode.[This is my screen before I press F5 to run, note "debug" selected in dropdown menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGbag.png)

I have also made sure optimizations are disabled in the C++ section of the properties menu of my project.

Comment: Are you building in Debug mode? What message shows in the tooltip when you put the mouse cursor on one of the black breakpoints (the message should indicate why the breakpoint could not be set)?

Comment: I'm building in debug mode. When I hover over the deactivated (black) breakpoints after running in debug mode, the banner says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type."

Comment: You're hitting F10 to step through the code right? (Or F11)

Answer (score 0):

You're building in Release mode.  Change your build to Debug mode.  Release builds are hard to debug, because many lines of code are compiled together, and thus cannot be individually broken upon.  If your breakpoints don't get set or hit properly, it's because you're in Release mode.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I selected debug mode and the problem still occurs (I believe I have always been in debug mode).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could check whether the `Solution Configuration` and `Properties` settings are consistent.
[image]

Moreover, it is not recommended that you set breakpoints on the `{` and `}` of the `if`, which will cause conditional compilation. Also, `compResult` is `false`, which means that the program cannot enter `if (compResult){}`.

Besides, I suggest that you could clean and rebuild the program. You could try to lear the `Require source files that exactly match the original version` option in `Debug->Options->Debugging->General`.